# How to use or emulate distinct in MySql paging

Tags: mysql, pagination, distinct

I have the following table:

```
ID   Category_ID  Score  Name
1    1            60     Name_1
2    1            50     Name_2
3    2            40     Name_3
4    3            30     Name_4
5    4            10     Name_5
```

lets say I run the following query:

```
SELECT * from table ORDER BY Score DESC LIMIT 0, 2
```

that will bring me:

```
ID   Category_ID  Score  Name
1    1            60     Name_1
2    1            50     Name_2
```

How can I avoid having repeated Category_ID (as much as possible) in my results but having as 1st condition the ORDER BY Score. For example, how can I get the following instead:

```
ID   Category_ID  Score  Name
1    1            60     Name_1
3    2            40     Name_3   <-- Following higher score with different Category_ID
```

and for

`SELECT * from table ORDER BY Score DESC LIMIT 1, 2` the expected results are:

```
ID   Category_ID  Score  Name
2    1            50     Name_2
4    3            30     Name_4
```

`SELECT * from table ORDER BY Score DESC LIMIT 2, 2`
the expected results are:

```
ID   Category_ID  Score  Name
5    4            10     Name_5
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to select only the ids that you want.  This will require a join back to the original table.  This version gives the result for the minimum id:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select category_id, min(id) as minid
      from t
      group by category_id
     ) tsum
     on t.id = tsum.minid
order by max_score
limit 0, 2
```

If you want the maximum score, instead:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select category_id, max(score) as maxscore
      from t
      group by category_id
     ) tsum
     on t.category_id = tsum.category_id and
        t.score = tsum.maxscore
order by max_score
limit 0, 2
```

Of course, this assumes that the max score only appears on one record.